# view page source in windows phone emulator

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, emulation

Can we see  page source code in windows phone emulator?

I need to check if any elements has set `display:none` in Emulator.

> So i need to view page source in windows phone emulator. Have you any idea for this?

Comment: There are a few apps that do this as their feature, or you could install a proxy like Fiddler to capture traffic on your PC that is being served to the phone.

Answer (score 0):

Your should try weinre to do this thing. http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2013/06/12/remote-html5-debugging-on-windows-phone-with-weinre.aspx